# CSS Works on custom Tag but not on DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a faq section for my webpage.

At first I used custom tags (Not registered just used custom names) and it worked fine but later I thought this could impact SEO so I moved from custom tag to vanilla `div`.

The custom tag version was working fine but as soon as I moved to `div` the CSS started behaving weirdly.

This is the code I am using  and the FAQ.css and the script that adds and removes the CSS :

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    gap: 10px;
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgb(185, 206, 185);

}

#faq {
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}

faqItem {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgb(194, 204, 204);
}

faqItem::after {
    display: grid;
    content: "";
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63, 60, 63);
}

faqItem h1 {
    display: grid;
    min-width: 95%;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

faqItem h1::before {
    display: grid;
    content: "+";
    width: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    justify-self: right;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

faqItem p {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 70ch;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out, visibility 0.15s ease;
}

/* Classes for Div */

.faqItem {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgb(194, 204, 204);
}

.faqItem::after {
    display: grid;
    content: "";
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63, 60, 63);
}

.faqItem h1 {
    display: grid;
    min-width: 95%;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faqItem h1::before {
    display: grid;
    content: "+";
    width: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    justify-self: right;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.faqItem p {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 70ch;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out, visibility 0.15s ease;
}

/* Common Class */
.changeIcon::before {
    content: "-";
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: content;
}

.showContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="faq.css">

<body>

<!-- Custom Tag -->

<article id="faq">
  <header>
      <h1>FAQs</h1>
  </header>

  <faqItem>
      <h1>Some My title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nulla atque, mollitia ducimus sit ut
          pariatur non ex vel asperiores voluptatibus eos est optio sequi nihil porro voluptates, repudiandae
          quam!
      </p> 
  </faqItem>
</article>

<!-- Vanilla Div -->

<article id="faq">
  <header>
      <h1>FAQs</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="faqItem">
      <h1>Some My title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nulla atque, mollitia ducimus sit ut
          pariatur non ex vel asperiores voluptatibus eos est optio sequi nihil porro voluptates, repudiandae
          quam!
      </p>
  </div>
</article>
</body> 

<script>
  // Function that will expand and shrink the faqItem
  function updateFAQItemState(elem) {
      elem.classList.contains("changeIcon")
          ? elem.classList.remove("changeIcon")
          : elem.classList.add("changeIcon");

      elem.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("showContent")
          ? elem.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("showContent")
          : elem.nextElementSibling.classList.add("showContent");
  }

  // Using Custom Tags (Not registered)
  let customFaqItems = [...document.getElementsByTagName("faqItem")];

  customFaqItems.forEach(element => {
      let h1 = element.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
      h1.onclick = function (ele) {
          updateFAQItemState(ele.target);
      }
  });
  // using DIV

  let divfaqItem = [...document.getElementsByClassName("faqItem")];
  divfaqItem.forEach(element => {
      let h1 = element.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
      h1.onclick = function (ele) {
          updateFAQItemState(ele.target);
      }
  })
</script>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fk6xbezw/1/

Question One :

Why the CSS is not working as expected?

Question Second :

Does using custom tag hurts SEO? (Registered or Unregistered if applicable)

Comment: Why is there a repeated `id` in HTML?

Comment: In real usage i just have one of those FAQ section. forgot to change while demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS definitions in

```
.faqItem p {
}
```

have precedence over those in

```
.showContent {
}
```

which negates almost all of the effects inside the `.showContent { .. }` block. You could change `.showContent {` to `.faqItem p.showContent {` for example to circumvent that.

---

## Why ?

In your old situation, while using a `<faqItem>` element, these 2 blocks of CSS contained the relevant code:

```
faqItem p {
    ...
    visibility: hidden;
    ...
}

.showContent {
    ...
    visibility: visible;
    ...
}
```

When you switched from using `<faqItem>` to `<div class="faqItem">` you changed

```
faqItem p {
    ...
}
```

to:

```
.faqItem p {
    ...
}
```

which is totally the right thing to do, and in most cases works out just fine, however the devil lies in the details as they say.

The statement `faqItem p` is a combination of two `element-selector`s; as in "for any `p` element located under a `faqItem` element ...".
The statement `.faqItem p` however, is one `class-selector` and one `element-selector`, and using a `class-selector` gives that block of CSS a higher level of `specificity`.

often enough, that won't matter much; but in your case you are trying to overrule the `visibility`-property (and others) inside here, with a `visibility`-property in `.showContent`.

Since `.showContent` consists of a single `class-selector` (which is pretty specific), it used to beat out those weak `faqItem p`-`element-selector`s.
However, since your new `.faqItem p` uses a `class-selector` plus an `element-selector`, it is **more** specific than `.showContent` which is only a `class-selector` by itself.

---

## So, the fix ?

```
/* Changing: */
.showContent { ... }
/* To: */
.faqItem .showContent { ... }
/* Or: */
.faqItem p.showContent { ... }
```

Changes the specificity of the `.showContent` so it again outweighs the `.faqItem p`.

You can read up more about `specificity` (and other rules of precedence) on many places, such as [here](https://medium.com/@saanstone/understanding-css-precedence-specificity-d8ca24712417).

There are alternate ways of accomplishing the same result. Some have been recommended in other comments now, but i feel fairly confident to claim those methods are less appropriate. It's worth knowing the rules of precedence and structuring your CSS to that affect.

Those other methods are similar to not understanding the rules of precedence for mathematical operators, and recommending people should write `(5*5) + (6*6)` at all times.

---

Comment: hello @Rexi can please elaborate more on this ? and possible than please look at the other question in the OP Question

Comment: sure, are you interested in the reason why ? or does the change not fix the problem ?

Comment: Yes the changes are working fine. But what's going on under the hood ?

Comment: Good detailed explanation @Raxi

Comment: @Raxi Thanks you for the explanation. Can you look at the second question please ?

Comment: Sure; i would suspect it to have no real negative side-effects; however i'm not much of an authority on SEO. Whenever possible, i try to "code to specification" so to say. Aim for correctness and only veer off that course if there is either serious benefit or if i am somehow seriously held back by doing so.

Comment: So personally, i would flip the question around, and ask: what benefit does using a custom element bring ? I don't know the answer, but cannot really picture many; hence i would go with `<div>`s myself. That said though, my feelings aren't that strong that i would rewrite already written (and functioning) code.

Comment: Well the bigger and only benefit i got was readability of html structure. it looked much cleaner. Still confused should i keep it or not

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the Javascript a little by using a delegated event listener bound to the `.faqItem` div elements but trigger the necessary accordion type code only when the event is actually registered upon the H1 element.

By negating the css content within `.faqItem p` ( ie: `.faqItem p:not(.showContent)` ) it seems to behave as expected?!

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.faqItem').forEach(div=>{
    div.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        if( e.target.tagName=='H1' ){
            let el=e.target;
            el.classList.toggle( 'changeIcon' );
            el.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle( 'showContent' )
        }
    })
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    gap: 10px;
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgb(185, 206, 185);
    
}

.faq {  /* ID attributes must be unique in the DOM !! */
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}


/* Classes for Div */

.faqItem {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgb(194, 204, 204);
}

.faqItem::after {
    display: grid;
    content: "";
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(63, 60, 63);
}

.faqItem h1 {
    display: grid;
    min-width: 95%;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faqItem h1::before {
    display: grid;
    content: "+";
    width: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    justify-self: right;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.faqItem p:not(.showContent) {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 70ch;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out, visibility 0.15s ease;
}

/* Common Class */
.changeIcon::before {
    content: "-";
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: content;
}

.showContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<article class="faq">
    <header>
        <h1>FAQs</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="faqItem">
        <h1>Some My title #1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nulla atque, mollitia ducimus sit ut
            pariatur non ex vel asperiores voluptatibus eos est optio sequi nihil porro voluptates, repudiandae
            quam!
        </p>
    </div>
</article>


<article class="faq">
    <header>
        <h1>FAQs</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="faqItem">
        <h1>Some My title #2</h1>
        <p>
        vel asperiores voluptatibus eos est optio sequi consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nulla atque, mollitia ducimus sit ut
            pariatur non ex.
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: +1 for the toggle part. Never knew that thing.  and using `.faqItem p:not(.showContent)` is  behaving different.