# media query not working with display property

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to hide the menubar when screen width is greater than 1200px, and show it when screen width is smaller than 1200px, but media query is not giving the result I want. I am using sass.

Here is my CSS:

```
        .icon {
            flex: 0.2;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding-right: 10px;

            .menubar {
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                **display: none;**

                i {
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 30px;
                    font-size: 30px;
                    line-height: 2;

                    &:hover {
                        color: $mainColor2;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

    .icon {
        .menubar {
            **display: flex;**
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my navbar React component:

```
<nav className='navbar' ref={navRef}>
                <div className="icon">
                    <div className="darkmode-button">
                        <DarkMode></DarkMode>
                    </div>
                    <div className="menubar" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>
                        {toggle ? <i class="fas fa-times" onClick={() => closeNav()} /> : <i class="fas fa-bars" onClick={() => openNav()} />}
                    </div>
                    <div className="language">
                        <Language></Language>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Flipping the `.menubar`s `display` between flex|none seems fine; perhaps it's being overruled somewhere else in your stylesheet ? use the browser tools content inspector (`Ctrl+Shift+C`) to see the values that are in effect.

Comment: @Raxi I see that ```display:none``` works perfertly, but if I drag the window to below 1200px, the style is still under ```display:none``` in the content inspector. I added a photo in my original post for you to see.

Comment: It is overruled. Seems like the style without media query is more specific than the original style so that it still applied the old style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've added the content inspector screenshot, it shows the `display` property is being applied using different selectors. I imagine that has likely caused a problem where the `flex`-variant doesn't have enough **specificity** to beat up the `none`-variant.

Your `display: none` applies to `.navbar .right .icon .menubar`,
but your `display: flex` applies to `.icon .menubar`.

I've written up an explanation for *why* this happens on another question before: [CSS Works on custom Tag but not on DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514332/css-works-on-custom-tag-but-not-on-div/66514452#66514452)

---

But the fix is likely to just wrap the `display: flex` within `.navbar { .right { ... } }` as well.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I changed my media query now to that, and it works now. Should be simple fix, but I messed up by not knowing what crossed out style means in content inspector. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool cool, that should do. I've added a link to the explanation in case *specificity* sounded like a new concept.